# Backtracking problem find number of vehicles for minimal cost

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I was trying to solve this problem:

*School attends competition. There are n students, who all need to arrive at the competition at the same time. The capacity of the bus is 50 students and it costs A euros, and the capacity of the taxi is 4 and it costs B euros. How many buses and taxis does the school need with minimal cost?*

Input:

n A B

Output:

num_of_buses numb_of_taxis

Using backtracking I found the minimal cost, but I can't find number of buses and taxis needed.
Here is my code:

```
int backtracking(int n, int a, int t){
    if(n<=0)
        return 0;

    int p1=a+backtracking(n-50,a,t);
    int p2=t+backtracking(n-4,a,t);
   
    return min(p1,p2);
}
```

My idea is that I need to find only number of buses and then calculate number of taxis, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Create a static variable that gets incremented everytime a recursive call is made through the `p1` line. This will contain the number of buses needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is c++ so we can return more than one thing at a time:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Solution {
    int cost;
    int busses;
    int taxis;
    Solution operator +(const Solution &other) {
        return Solution{cost + other.cost, busses + other.busses,
                        taxis + other.taxis};
    }
    bool operator <=>(const Solution &other) {
        return cost - other.cost;
    }
};

enum {
    SEATS_BUS = 50,
    SEATS_TAXI = 4,
};

Solution backtracking(int students, int bus_cost, int taxi_cost) {
    if (students <= 0)
        return Solution{0, 0, 0};

    Solution bus = backtracking(students - SEATS_BUS, bus_cost, taxi_cost) 
                 + Solution{bus_cost, 1, 0};
    Solution taxi = backtracking(students - SEATS_TAXI, bus_cost, taxi_cost) 
                  + Solution(taxi_cost, 0, 1};

    return min(bus, taxi);     
}

int main() {
    int students, bus_cost, taxi_cost;
    std::cout << "Enter number of students, cost for bus, cost for taxi: ";
    std::cin >> students >> bus_cost >> taxi_cost;
    Solution s = backtracking(students, bus_cost, taxi_cost);
    std::cout << "cost = " << s.cost << ", #buses = " << s.busses
              << ", #taxis = " << s.taxis << std::endl;
}
```

This is a horrible solution to the problem though. It does an exhaustive search of all possible solutions, which has exponential runtime. Try finding a solution for 600 students as an example how this doesn't scale.

Or rather it is a horrible problem to demonstrate the method. Isn't there a better example that is both simple and benefits from backtracking?

Comment: I had the idea of returning more values at once but didn't know how, so thank you for your time implementing this. I know backtracking has high time complexity, so I thought once I do it I could optimize it with memoization or build it with DP. This problem is in my school materials for learning backtracking/DP, so I am trying to do it that way.